# How to simulate network packet loss when streaming video?

Tags: testing, video, wireshark, rtp, packet-loss

Please help me solve this tricky problem, making me suffering for almost one week.

How to make streaming video suffering packet loss?

Switch: Pica8 3290 
Computer: core i7 2600, 8GB 
Link: 100Mps 
Streaming video : RTP (1080P、4K)

I've already tried "iperf", "iperf3" and "Packeth" to generate UDP packets. However, these 3 sofwares seem to measure the residual capacity of the link first and then send the amount of the packets fit the capacity.

E.g.:

(No Video streaming) iperf send almost 100Mps

(With video streaming) iperf only send almost 70Mbps

Thus, these packet generator won't help me to make the streaming video suffering serious loss. (What I want is make huge traffic and make the streaming suffering terrible loss and delay)

So, how can I create "congestion" and make the video streaming packets loss ?

Truly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Hey Shine Hsu, have you tried my solution? Can you please mark it as answer if it was helpful? Thanks!

Comment: of course, if it'll still not any better anwaers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently Facebook has released a promising tool called ATC (A tool to simulate network conditions).

It allows you to controlled bandwith, latency, packet loss and packet corruption rates in your network.

Hovewer the tool supports only Linux platforms and Python 2.7.

You can find general information about ATC [here](http://facebook.github.io/augmented-traffic-control/). ATCs github repo is [here](https://github.com/facebook/augmented-traffic-control).

Answer (score 2):

In Linux there is a special utility [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem), which provides all functionality you are looking for out of the box on Linux kernel layer.

For Windows platform you can use [Network Emulator Toolkit](http://itband.ru/2010/07/network-emulator-toolkit/).